# I can not get MVVM to work

Tags: c#, mvvm, winrt-xaml, mvvm-light

I am desperately trying to implement MVVM and for some reason it is not working. I am using MVVM light on a Windows 8.1 Store App.

What am I doing wrong? I followed three tutorials by now and nothing seems to work..

I retrieve the Data from a Webservice and that part 100% works just fine. The ObservableCollection contains data.

The rest of my code looks like this:

ViewModelLocator:

```
public ViewModelLocator()
{
    ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

    if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
    {
        // Create design time view services and models
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDesignTimeWeatherServiceLayer, DesignTimeWeatherServiceLayer>();
    }
    else
    {
        // Create run time view services and models
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IWeatherServiceLayer, WeatherServiceLayer>();
    }

    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<WeatherViewModel>();
}


public WeatherViewModel Weather
{
    get
    {
        return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<WeatherViewModel>();
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class WeatherViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    WeatherServiceLayer serviceLayer = new WeatherServiceLayer();

    public async void GetAllWeatherData()
    {
        WeatherData = await serviceLayer.GetAllWeatherAsync();
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Weather> weatherData;
    public ObservableCollection<Weather> WeatherData { get { return weatherData; } set { weatherData = value; RaisePropertyChanged("WeatherData"); } }
}
```

Code Behind:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    WeatherViewModel vm = new WeatherViewModel();
    vm.GetAllWeatherData();
}
```

View:

```
...
DataContext="{Binding Weather, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <GridView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource WeatherItemTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding Weather.WeatherData, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"/>
</Grid>
```

DataTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="WeatherItemTemplate">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Temperature}" Height="60" Margin="15,0,15,0"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding WeekDay}" Margin="15,0,15,10"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Although you've provided a lot of detail about what you are doing, it may help you to get an answer by better describing what "it is not working" means. What actually happens when you run the app vs. what did you expect to happen?

Comment: That’s not how you set up the data context with MVVM Light. Either you use the view model locator (which requires you to set it up as a resource), or you create the view model in the code behind and assign the data context there.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. When I start the App I expect data to show up inside my GridView. Instead I see nothing.

Comment: Your code behind doesn't make sense. If your using a viewmodellocator you should set this up in your app.xaml as a application data source and then set your data context to the weather property. Try setting up some break points in your class constructors to see what is getting called.

Comment: THANKS! You were right. I moved the call for GetAllWeatherAsync from the CodeBehind to the constructor of the ViewModel and it all worked just fine - even the deisgner shows data now :)

Comment: Be careful having data access in your constructor and design time view - it can dramatically slow your designer down as it constantly rebuilds.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but there are a couple things that seem suspect to me.  Initially you set your DataContext property.  Are your sure your DataContext is what you're expecting after this assignment?  You can set a breakpoint in your view's constructor after you call InitializeComponent to check.

Further in your ItemsSource binding you're saying "Weather.WeatherData" sourced by your locator.  This seems redundant and maybe wrong.  Maybe just try "WeatherData" and remove the Source specification.  If your DataContext is a Weather, then that will be the object used for all bindings in that xaml file.